# C# file wont copy

Tags: c#, file, copy

Hi  i am trying to copy a file from one pc(my server) to another PC(client PC) i have set up the connection and everything works great the connection is made but as soon as i try and copy a file i get an error.

```
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
          /*  DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
             DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
             dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl,
                                                              InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,
                                                              PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
             dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);*/
            if (Directory.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)+"\\Database"))
            {
                if (!File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb"))
                {
                    File.Copy(@"C:\Program Files\Group 27\Bookstore Bargainers\new itrw225 data1.mdb", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
                }

            } 
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database");
                File.Copy(@"C:\Program Files\Group 27\Bookstore Bargainers\new itrw225 data1.mdb", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
            }
        });

        Size = new Size(456, 292);
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            try
            {
                mydb = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\\\192.0.8.100\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
                mydb.Open();
                mydb.Close();
                Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\\\192.0.8.100\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb";
                File.Copy("\\192.0.8.100\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb", @"C:\ProgramData\Database\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex + "");
                Properties.Settings.Default.ServerOnline = false;
                mydb = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
                MessageBox.Show("Server not detected. Program will function as normally with the database stored on this pc");
                Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb";
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        });
```

my erroe occurs in the following line

```
File.Copy("\\192.0.8.100\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb", @"C:\ProgramData\Database\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
```

Here is the error message

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '\192.0.8.100\Database\new itrw225 data1.mdb

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String        destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
at BookstoreBargainerSystem.Form1.<Form1_Load>b__13_1() in C:\Users\ipadc\Desktop\projek\Bookstore Bargainer System (8 Sept)\BookstoreBargainerSystem\Login.cs:line 79
```

any help would be much appreciated. i am 100% sure both of these files exist

updated code

```
 this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
          /*  DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
             DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
             dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl,
                                                              InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,
                                                              PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
             dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);*/
            if (Directory.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)+"\\Database"))
            {
                if (!File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb"))
                {
                    File.Copy(@"C:\Program Files\Group 27\Bookstore Bargainers\new itrw225 data1.mdb", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
                }

            } 
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database");
                File.Copy(@"C:\Program Files\Group 27\Bookstore Bargainers\new itrw225 data1.mdb", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
            }
        });

        Size = new Size(456, 292);
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            try
            {
                mydb = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\\\192.0.8.100\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
                mydb.Open();
                mydb.Close();
                Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\\\192.0.8.100\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb";
                File.Copy("\\\\192.0.8.100\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.ServerOnline = false;
                mydb = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb");
                MessageBox.Show("Server not detected. Program will function as normally with the database stored on this pc");
                Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Database\\new itrw225 data1.mdb";
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        });
```

Comment: it looks like you are trying to copy from an IP address... looking at the error, it's escaping out the first backslash because that character is also the escape character.  try `\\\\192....` instead, or try using the `@` for a string literal, like you did for the second argument.

Comment: tried both of thos. still same error

Comment: it couldn't be **exactly the same error** if you tried those options, because the string would be different, unless the error is being generated on a different line of code.  Post the new path that it doesn't like, after the attempts?

Comment: There i showed my updated code. Still the same error message

Comment: again, the error is **exactly the same**?  With ***exactly the same number of backslashes??** I doubt that.

Comment: Use File.Copy(@"\\192.0.8.100\Database\new itrw225 data1.mdb", @"C:\ProgramData\Database\new itrw225 data1.mdb"); If that doesn't work is it a credential problem?